# Hide or show div according data json in Astro's component

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have site.json in my project with a lot of strings of data.
How can I read the json file and hide or show specific div according to JSON data?
Since my projects, for which I create components, do not all contain references to githab or have a domain name, I need to show svg only to those that have such links in json.

Projects.astro:

```
---
import ProjectItem from './ProjectItem.astro';
import site from "../data/site.json";
const title = `Projects I’ve been working on`;
const {projects} = site;
---
<section id="projects">
    <h3>{title}</h3>
        {projects.map((item) => (
            <ProjectItem item={item} />
        ))}
</section>
```

In ProjectItem.astro pay attention please to "div class="external" where created two links for external link and project's github. I want to create them if in site.json there is specific information for each my project. Now these links are created in any case, have information about githab or domain name or not. I tried to write a script in javascript, but I couldn’t.

'ProjectItem.astro':

```
---
const { item } = Astro.props;
---
<div class="project-item-grid">
    <div class="project-item-right">
        <div class="external">
            <a href={item.link} class="link">
                <img src="assets/external_link_100.svg" />
            </a>
            <a href={item.github} class="link">
                <img src="assets/github_100.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my site.json. I made it smaller because it’s big. But notice the "projects", especially projects->link and projects->github.

```
{
"skills": {
      "comfortable": [
            {...}],
      "familiar": [
            {...}],
},
"projects": [
      {
        "title": "Title1",
        "link": "link1.com",
        "github": "link1.github.io"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title2",
        "link": "link2.com",
        "github":             // information is absent. I think you can put null or "" instead an empty field.
      },
        "title": "Title3",
        "link": ,             // now link's information is absent.
        "github": "link3.github.io"           
      },
... etc.
]}
```

---

There I have tryed to solve the problem myself with JS:

```
const file = require('../data/site.json');
try {
      const data = JSON.parse(file)
     } catch(err) {
         console.error(err)
     }
for (let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (data.projects[i].github === null) {
            document.getElementById('github').style.display = 'none'
            console.log("Catch!");
        } else {
            console.log("No catch");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the `github` key from projects that don't use it?

Comment: <a style={item.link? ' ':'display:none'} href={item.link} class="link"> and <a style={item.github? ' ':'display:none'} href={item.github} class="link"> Try replacing this <a> tags in your code.

Comment: Michael M., I think I can, but I don't know how to make it workable :P

Comment: @OmkarPattanaik, oh, You are incredible! I have been struggling with this problem for more than two days! And here your answer worked, thank you very much)
And it's very simple and beautiful, what I wanted. Just for curiousity, can you please advice how I need to change your piece of code if I will delete keys github or link as Michael M. said?

Comment: Great !! Just sharing it as Answer.

Comment: @Sergo .. I don't think any change will be needed. This answer will work even if those key are removed from json.

Comment: Accepted the answer) Oh, yeah, you're right. I just didn't delete the comma :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

Just used ternary operator to hide null or undefined value.

```
---
const { item } = Astro.props;
---
<div class="project-item-grid">
    <div class="project-item-right">
        <div class="external">
            <a style={item.link? ' ':'display:none'} href={item.link} class="link"> 
                <img src="assets/external_link_100.svg" />
            </a>
            <a style={item.github? ' ':'display:none'} href={item.github} class="link">
                <img src="assets/github_100.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an expression in your template works.

```
---
const { item } = Astro.props;
---
<div class="project-item-grid">
    <div class="project-item-right">
        <div class="external">
            {
                item ? <a href={item.link} class="link"><img src="assets/external_link_100.svg" /></a> : ''
            }
            {
                item ? <a href={item.github} class="link"><img src="assets/github_100.png" /></a> : ''
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could easily abstract this logic into a function to make it nicer to read or make your button a component to shorten the markup in this template.